# Action class alternative for marionette driver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, gecko, firefox-marionette

Below is  code to draw a rectangle in selenium webdriver which i was using, but after switching to marionette driver, it stopped working as Action class is still not supported, 
is there any other alternative, like in javascript, 
robot class is not working in my case as script will be running on remote system.

code:

```
   Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
   builder.clickAndHold(shareview).moveByOffset(AppGlobalConst.X, AppGlobalConst.Y)
            .moveByOffset(AppGlobalConst.Y, AppGlobalConst.X).moveByOffset(AppGlobalConst.Z, AppGlobalConst.W)
            .moveByOffset(AppGlobalConst.W, AppGlobalConst.Z).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to not use a Firefox version higher than 46, until Marionette has feature parity with Firefox Driver.